# In makefile, how to use static pattern rules with file name containing dollar sign?

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

I have .c files need to be compiled, for example:

```
$main.c
$print.c
...
```

They were generated by another program. I would like to write a makefile that will compile them separately so that I can do it with `-j 8`.

My plan was to use static pattern rules like the following:

```
SRCS = $(wildcard ./*.c)
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(U_SRC))

$(OBJS):%.o:%.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

However, due to the dollar sign, the file names cannot be correctly recognized. I tried to replace the dollar sign with double dollar sign, but still doesn't work.

How can I do this and make the compilation easy?

Comment: Ugh, I feel sorry for you. Make is so ill-equipped to handle weird file names.

Comment: Is there any possibility you can rename the files and strip off the dollar signs?

Comment: @johnkugelman I may use `rename` to do that ..... But this will break the script, each time before compilation I need to rename them

Comment: @johnkugelman actually, the sub directory is also created randomly, so each time I'll need to re-evaluate it with regular expression. Is there a way that I can replace the '$' with '$$'?? so that makefile will recognize it as a dollar sign

Comment: Re. `"But this will break the script, each time before compilation I need to rename them"`: is the generation of these files not part of the make/build process?  If not, why not?  It would probably make things a lot easier to manage, right?

Comment: @g.m. The reason of this is that the compilation progress will create a bunch of temp files into a random created sub-directory. Makefile only evaluate it's variable at the beginning, and the re-evaluated variables cannot be a prerequisite. So it has to break into two parts.........

Comment: Make is actually fine with almost all weird filenames: only names containing whitespace are problematic.  In particular, the above makefile is not in any way a problem for **make**.  However, remember that all recipes are actually run in the _shell_, and the _shell_ has a lot of rules about special filenames.  If you want to use them in your recipe you must escape them from the _shell_, not from make.

Answer (score 0):

All right........

Here is a success experiment in my environment:

```
C_TMP = $(wildcard *.c)
C_OBJ = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(C_TMP))

$(C_OBJ):%.o:%.c
    gcc -g -c \$< -o \$@ 


test: $(C_OBJ)
    @echo $(C_OBJ)
```

And the result is

```sh
[shore@shore-82b6 exam]$ make test
gcc -g -c \$main.c -o \$main.o 
gcc -g -c \$print.c -o \$print.o 
.o .o
```

Comment: As I mentioned above: you can see that in fact there is _nothing_ special you need to do in your makefile to allow names containing `$` returned from `wildcard`.  However, to use those weird names you must escape them from the _shell_ because the shell treats `$` as special.  IMO the above solution is not great.  It only works if the _first_ character of the filename needs to be treated specially.  You should instead use single quotes: `gcc -g -c '$<' -o '$@'`.  This handles all special chars anywhere in the filename, except single quotes themselves (that is doable but harder).

Comment: @madscientist I've encountered a new problem that containing '%' in the file name T T,.,,,,